# Photo Gallery page loads extremely slow

Tags: css, html, web

my photo gallery page takes way to long to load. Are there any simplier ways? I tried making the images all small to load quicker, but it is still very slow and will at times freeze.

It is about 60 photos.

CSS:

```
#center img
        {
        opacity:0.5;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
        }

#center img:hover
        {
        opacity:1.0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
        }

#center {
            float: left;
            margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;
            min-width: 200px; width: 494px; border-radius:8px; 
        }
#center  a img {
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 145px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--hide

var password;
var pass1="maze";
password=prompt('Please enter your password to view this page!',' ');
if (password==pass1)
  alert('Password Correct! Click OK to enter page you mazers!');
else
   {
    window.location="http://fun256.com/photos/411.png";
   } 
//-->
</script>




<title>Predict the Result</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="april.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="container" class="clearfix">
     <!-- Header --> <!-- Left Column -->
     <div id="center">
     <a href="IMG_0590.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0590.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a href="IMG_0591.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0591.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /> </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a href="IMG_0592.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0592.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /> </a>
     <a href="IMG_0593.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0593.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /> </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a href="IMG_0594.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0594.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /> </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a href="IMG_0595.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0595.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /> </a><a href="IMG_0596.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0596.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
     <a href="IMG_0597.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0597.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /> </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0598.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0598.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /> </a>
    <a href="IMG_0599.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0599.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /> </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0600.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0600.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /> </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="IMG_0601.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0601.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /> </a> <a href="IMG_0602.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0602.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /> </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="IMG_0530big.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0530.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /> </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_6098.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_6098.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="IMG_0531.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0531.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0532.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0532.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0533.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0533.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="IMG_0534.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0534.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0535.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0535.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0536.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0536.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="IMG_0537.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0537.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0538.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0538.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0539.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0539.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="IMG_0540.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0540.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0541.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0541.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <a href="IMG_0542.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0542.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a><a href="IMG_0543.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0543.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <a href="IMG_0544.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0544.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0545.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0545.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="IMG_0546.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0546.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0547.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0587.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a href="IMG_0548.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0548.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a><a href="IMG_0549.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0549.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <a href="IMG_0550.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0550.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0551.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0551.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="IMG_0552.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0552.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0553.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0553.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a href="IMG_0554.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0554.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a><a href="IMG_0555.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0555.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <a href="IMG_0556.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0556.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0557.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0557.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>
   <a href="IMG_0558.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0558.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="IMG_0559.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0559.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
   <a href="IMG_0560.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="IMG_0560.jpg" height="228" width="304" alt="" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div>Copyright "Younani" Michael Younani 2012</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be showing the full-sized image for the gallery, and resizing it with html. This is not best practice, as it requires the user to download all images at full resolution. 60 of them is just too many, and is probably over 10mb in downloads, at a guess.

Also, using width and height to resize images is not good for performance.

The answer is **thumbnails**.
You must make a smaller copy of every image, and use this in the link of your slideshow, instead of just showing a squashed version of the full-size image.

You can also use some form of lazy loading, where an image is only shown when it is needed.

It looks like you're doing this by hand, so you might find generating a web album in Picasa to be a quick and easy to to make thumbnails.

I hope this helps.